# New way of representing floating point

Tags: floating-point

I want to create a new way of representing floating point. In standard IEEE floating point, we have 1 bit to represent sign, 8 bits to represent exponential and 23 bits to represent significand. In the new floating point system, I keep the breakdown of sign/exp/significand but there is no implicit 1 (assume there is no denormalized numbers). For example, in this new scheme to represent 3, we have sign bit 0, exponential bit 0x7F and significand 0x000003. Does this new system of floating point represent a larger unique numeric values than IEEE standard point? My thought is that since both systems have the same breakdown they represent the same number of unique numeric values

Comment: To give any answer you first need to fully define the 'new' representation. One example, of how it represents one number is not such a definition.

Comment: In addition, it seems that in your system numbers doesn't have a unique representation for all numbers.
e.g. 2^0 * 1.0 == 2^1 *0.5 as far as I can tell from your description is that those could be represented differently in your system. The ambiguity reduces the numbers representable considerably.

Comment: So, it just seems like a denormalized number. The problem with that is that you will have multiple representations of the same number. 0x7F x 0x000001 and 0x7E x 0x000002, foor example. That's what plshelp has already pointed out. To really have a considerably better space use than IEEE you'd need to have logarithmic numbers, i.e. to store a log of some base, but it would considerably reduce speed.